# How would someone "escape" a black hole?

Tags: interstellar

In the 2014 movie "Interstellar" the main character Cooper gets trapped in a black hole and relays data about it to his daughter Murph. What I don't get is if nothing, including light, can escape a black hole, then how is he found by Rangers out of a black hole? My understanding is that black holes are essentially huge gravitational nets in space that nothing can escape. If light can't escape, how does a human escape something like this?